# Boolean complementation '' mark

Tags: logic

I am trying to read Smullyan A Beginners Guide to Mathematical Logic and there is mentioned under ' Complementation ', page 11/12 that **A''** is **A** itself - so why to bother to mark it with a double apostrophe at all( I hope I am right how this mark is called) if it could be just be written **A** without any **'**?

I suspect it is really a silly question - Sorry about that - but I am trying to understand what's the point of it? Any clarification really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is presumably to demonstrate this very property of [double negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation): for classical logic, [complementation involutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)#Mathematical_logic) (i.e., for every *a*, *a''* is logically equivalent to *a*).

Note that *p* and *p''* are structurally distinct, even though truth-equivalent. An *application* of a rule that complementation involutes is "required" to reduce one to the other.

Comment: Perhaps I will understand it better when reading further - at the moment it is too difficult to understand.